# Set Theory to prove $A$ and $B$ are subset of each other if each element $x$ belong to $A$ each element belongs to $B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

On the slides provided by the professor, she has presented a theorem called sandwich theorem which states:

$$
A=B  \\ is \ the \ same \ thing \ as \\
 A\subseteq B \subseteq A
\\ is \ the \ same \ thing \ as \\
 \ for \ each \ element \ x: x \in A \iff x \in B
  $$

This is something easy to know, but how am I able to prove it properly with math languages? How can I come from the first statement to the final one and prove they are equal to each other?

Comment: When you ask how to prove "obvious" things it is important to say what you are working with.  In ZFC set theory, the [axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) is explicity the equivalence between your first and your third.  If you want to prove that, you need to have something equivalent.  What is it?

Comment: Oh sorry, because I am just a first-year student studying Discrete Math as part of my CS program. So excuse me if I don't know I need to put this :( The professor just ask us to prove using proper math language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say (as sets) $A = B$ is to say that $A$ and $B$ consist of exactly the same elements, i.e. $x \in A \implies x \in B$ and $x \in B \implies x \in A$. This is equivalent to $x \in A \iff x \in B$, which is the last statement. The middle statement follows by definition of subset: $X \subseteq Y$ means $x \in X \implies x \in Y$. Applying this to the definition stated in the first sentence gives $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$, respectively. Putting these together:
$$
A \subseteq B \subseteq A.
$$